# xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, xen

We're running Ubuntu 14.04 on an EC2 virtual machine. I've been seeing a lot of these errors in our kernel log:

```
[  704.032085] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
[  736.096102] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
[  768.160075] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
[  800.224082] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
[  832.288094] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
```

We obviously aren't running Xen within our virtual machine, so these must indicate something to do with the host's allocation of memory. I don't believe it's causing any immediate problems for us, but is it something we should be concerned about?

Comment: You should contact Amazon.

Comment: This appears to be a known issue with EC2 right now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1304001

Comment: This has been on going for a fair while now. :\

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in few HVM EC2 servers.

It is unclear if the issue is in the kernel or Amazon's configuration for EC2.

You'll have to add/use the following `PPA` to fix this:

https://launchpad.net/~inaddy/+archive/ubuntu/lp1304001

Using this PPA resolved the issue for most of the users.

Ref: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1304001